# How to get both the numeric return value and the select statement from a stored procedure concurrently?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, dapper

I've been tasked with replacing one of those nasty "GUI-based programming" things that businesses sometimes buy when trying to shrink their programming staff with a .Net Core app using Dapper (now that they've realized it was a horrible mistake and made garbage code).

I am not permitted to change the stored procs as it stands.

The proc being called contains two values, a `select` statement and a `return` value, which were both retrieved somehow by the app.  We can't see how the app did it; this is obfuscated in proprietary "core" libraries.   It looks something like this:

```
--things it does
Select Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 from TheTable;
Return 0; --success
```

(I cannot paste the actual query because we have aggressive cybersecurity, but this is the base logic behind it.  There are no OUT params.)

When I use Dapper's `ExecuteAsync(` method, I only get a return value of 0 or null, depending on the return value. I've tried changing it to a Query , but i always get null, even if there is a value giving the same params to the proc in SSMS.

```
var result = await _dbc.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>("storedproc", paramsObject);
```

How can I also fetch the results of the select statement *without* altering the stored procedure to return both in variables?

Comment: Please show us the dapper code you are using? How does the stored procedure look like? Is it using OUT parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Add an output parameter to capture the return code.

EG

```
var result = await _dbc.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>("exec @rc = storedproc", paramsObject);
```

Or use CommandType.Stored procedure with a ReturnValue parameter.  Per [Passing Output parameters to stored procedure using dapper in c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353881/passing-output-parameters-to-stored-procedure-using-dapper-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the return code that contains the required data; we're looking to get the dataset that results from the proc.

Comment: Daper's `Queryxxx` methods return the resultset from the proc.  If you get confused, just revert to `ExecuteReader()` with a parameterized SQL statement.  That's the lowest-level API to run queries, and exposes the most functionality.